# GXT Sencha Copying a liststore

Tags: java, extjs, store, gxt, deep-copy

What is the best way to copy a ListStore? I am aware that the ListStore does not have an iterator, so I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to copy this rather than the following code:

```
private final ListStore<LineObject> storeA = new ListStore<LineObject>(new ModelKeyProv()); 
private ListStore<LineObject> storeB = new ListStore<LineObject>(new ModelKeyProv());

public void copy(){
    List<LineObject> lineListData = storeA.getAll();

    for(LineObject line: lineListData){
            storB.add(line);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
storeA.addAll(storeB.getAll());
```

This is the efficient way to copy a listStore data from one to another as far as I know.
Thanks